# Undefined reference to static variable c++

Tags: c++, static

Hi i am getting undefined reference error in the following code:

```
class Helloworld{
  public:
     static int x;
     void foo();
};
void Helloworld::foo(){
     Helloworld::x = 10;
};
```

I don't want a `static` `foo()` function. How can I access `static` variable of a class in non-`static` method of a class?

Answer (score 154):

> I don't want a `static` `foo()` function

Well, `foo()` is *not* static in your class, and you do *not* need to make it `static` in order to access `static` variables of your class.

What you need to do is simply to provide a *definition* for your static member variable:

```
class Helloworld {
  public:
     static int x;
     void foo();
};

int Helloworld::x = 0; // Or whatever is the most appropriate value
                       // for initializing x. Notice, that the
                       // initializer is not required: if absent,
                       // x will be zero-initialized.

void Helloworld::foo() {
     Helloworld::x = 10;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot man. I was instantiating HelloWorld::x but not with int.
Once again thanks.

Comment: @AndyProwl I tried this and got a compiler error on the line that sets x to 0. It says 'foo' in 'class Helloworld' does not name a type. Any advice?

Comment: @ufmike semicolon at the end of `foo()` definition is causing the error.

Comment: Do I have to use Helloword:: __x__ inside Helloworld::foo()? can I just use __x__?

Comment: @schantischul you don't need to qualify `x` with `Helloworld`.

Answer (score 78):

The code is correct, but incomplete. The class `Helloworld` has a **declaration** of its static data member `x`, but there is no **definition** of that data member. Somehwere in your source code you need

```
int Helloworld::x;
```

or, if 0 isn't an appropriate initial value, add an initializer.

Answer (score 56):

Old question, but;

Since `c++17` you can declare `static` members `inline` and instantiate them inside the body of `class` without the need of an `out-of-class` definition:

```
class Helloworld{
  public:
     inline static int x = 10;
     void foo();
};
```

Comment: This also makes it significantly easier to initialize a private static variable (instance pointer) for a singleton class.