# undefined reference with a static instance

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-variables

I am currently porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw GCC.
It seems there is a problem when I attempt to use a static variable .
This code works fine in Visual studio so I am not sure what the problem might be here. I have pasted an outline of what the code looks like. If this is insufficient I could put in more.

```
Header file: .h
namespace LG_Wrapper
{
    template <LG_Thread Thread>
    class EffectApplication : public ktApplication
    {
    public:
    static EffectApplication<Thread>& GetInstance();
    protected:
        .....
        .....
        static boost::recursive_mutex mResource;
      }
}

DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(EffectApplication);


Source File: .cpp
namespace LG_Wrapper
{

    template<>
    boost::recursive_mutex  EffectApplication<LG_Thread_NAME>::mResource;  //LG_Thread_NAME type discussed below

    template <LG_Thread Thread>
    EffectApplication<Thread>& EffectApplication<Thread>::GetInstance()
    {
        boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock mutex( mResource ); //Error with mResource

        static EffectApplication<Thread> instance;
        return instance;
    }
    ....
}
```

Now I am not sure about the `LG_Thread_NAME` type. 
After going through the code I noticed that I define the following in the project settings

```
LG_THREAD_NAME=GAME
```

This definition comes into play with this macro somewhere else in the code

```
#define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...)
```

I am having issue accessing `mResource` The code builds fine if I comment out the statement

```
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock mutex( mResource );
```

Any suggestions on why I might be getting the following error with the above code ?

```
(.text$_ZN10KT_Wrapper17EffectApplicationILNS_9LT_ThreadE0EE11GetInstanceEv[_ZN10LT_Wrapper17EffectApplicationILNS_9LT_ThreadE0EE11GetInstanceEv]+0x11): undefined reference to `LT_Wrapper::EffectApplication<(LT_Wrapper::LT_Thread)0>::mResource'
```

**Update:**
I am certain that there is something wrong with the variable mResource because in the static method. If I do this it builds fine

```
  boost::recursive_mutex l;
boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock mutex( l );
```

**Duplicate Question Issue:**
I am not sure how this question is a duplicate of the links provided. In all the links provided the ops have not initialized their static variables. Here I have initialized my static variable outside the class.

Comment: Did you include the `boost` in the include path?

Comment: Yes I did. I am using a lot of boost libraries in the project. And the boost libraries are included. I have also used `-lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-d-1_57` flag when building

Comment: Did you give a definition of `mResource` in a translation unit? Not a declaration (like you have there), but a definition. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284629/undefined-reference-to-static-variable-c) and [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145299/why-the-static-data-members-have-to-be-defined-outside-the-class-separately-in-c).

Comment: @Cornstalks I am not sure what you mean. I have given an initializing value for  the static variable which is in the source file as such `boost::recursive_mutex  EffectApplication<LG_Thread_NAME>::mResource;`

Comment: I am not sure how this is a duplicate. I have initialized the static object outside the class. In the links provided the OPS have not done that

Comment: Are you compiling and linking to that source file?

Comment: Yes. Also could you tell me how this question is a duplicate ? I might be missing something then because from what I have read from those posted links I am already doing that.

Comment: @JamesFranco: It would be a whole lot easier to tell you what you're doing wrong if you provided a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My guess is that it has to do with how your definition is a `template <>` that only covers `LG_Thread_NAME` (rather than a truly generic `template <LG_Thread thread>`). If you can provide enough details to prove this isn't a duplicate and properly demonstrate what the issue is, then I'll vote to reopen. But as it is, there's not enough details here for me to be convinced otherwise. That MVCE thing I mentioned is critical.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Ill try to build a working example and update this post. thanks

Comment: So I updated the question with more finding. Apparently I did not mention a macro being involved. I just added that - Hopefully that would reopen the question

Answer (score 0):

The initialization

```
template<>
boost::recursive_mutex  EffectApplication<LG_Thread_NAME>::mResource;
```

still is not correct, since you initialize `mResource` not for all template parameter, but only for specialization with `LG_Thread_NAME`. So I guess when you try to access it with some another template parameter you've got an error.

Correct way is like this

```
template<LG_Thread Thread>
boost::recursive_mutex  EffectApplication<Thread>::mResource;
```

Also I'm not sure with my answer because the error says that the problem is with `LT_Wrapper` class and template parameter `(LT_Wrapper::LT_Thread)0` looks strange to me.