# Variadic Macros

Tags: c++, macros

I came across this code that involved variadic Macros and I wanted to know what that meant

```
#define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...)  //This all of the macro - I am not holding out on anything
```

Now There is this class as this

```
Header file: .h
    namespace LG_Wrapper
    {
        template <LG_Thread Thread>
        class EffectApplication : public ktApplication
        {
        public:
        static EffectApplication<Thread>& GetInstance();
        protected:
            .....
            .....
            static boost::recursive_mutex mResource;
          }
    }

    DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(EffectApplication);  <---- What does this do ?
```

I wanted to know what effect the macro has ?

**Update:**
I have received numerous downvotes on this as this question gives of the impression that something is missing that I did not post the entire content of the macro. There is nothing more to the macro. I wish there was. This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662190/undefined-reference-with-a-static-instance) which was closed. The macro literally just ends after (...)

```
 #define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...)
```

but there isnt. That is one of the reason why I am here as I am not sure how to deal with this situation. Does this macro have not effect then ?

**More Info:**

This is what I have in another file
I am using the following defined in my project setting

```
LG_WRAPPER_EXPORTS
LG_THREAD_NAME=GAME
```

Following is the code

```
namespace LG_Wrapper
{

enum LG_Thread
{
    GAME,
    OTHER
};


/*
If the library itself is including this file
*/
#ifdef LG_WRAPPER_EXPORTS

    #ifndef LG_THREAD_NAME
        #error You must define LG_THREAD_NAME!
    #endif

    //Legacy types should not be used internally
    #define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...)

#else // LG_WRAPPER_EXPORTS

    //Legacy typenames are provided for convenience to the client
    #define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(ClassType) \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::##ClassType##<LG_Wrapper::GAME>             ClassType; \

#endif // LG_WRAPPER_EXPORTS

}
```

Comment: It is just here to skip something which became useless.

Comment: Can #define be used with "..." like this? Seems like there there is something missing.

Comment: @AlainD: Yes, variadic macros.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html  But this one expands to nothing at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck so does this mean it nullfies the type or something.  I know  that inorder to get rid of SAL based annotation in gcc they are defined with  nothing.

Comment: @JamesFranco: Most likely if a compiler flag is set it's defined to do something else, such as declaring legacy types.  With the _current_ compiler flags, it doesn't need to do anything, so it doesn't do anything.,

Comment: Let me update the code. Where the compiler flags are set.

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: @JamesFranco So it's exactly like MooingDuck's answer, except that `...` isn't used for variadicity, but for avoiding a pointless parameter name in the empty case.

Comment: @molbdnilo: It's still used for variadicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually pretty common, but it depends on other code that wasn't mentioned in the other code you looked at:

```
#if USING_OLD_COMPILER //when using an older compiler, use this to declare legacy types
#define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...) STUFF(__VA_ARGS__)    
#else //new compiler doesn't have to do anything special
#define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(...)
#endif


//in older compilers we had to declare legacy types for this
//newer compilers don't need this step, so this does nothing at all in them.
DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(EffectApplication);
```

I don't actually know this macro, so I don't know it's actual purpose.  But it's common to see macros without definitions for similar tricks as this.