# Why is class name used before the variable name together with "::"?

Tags: c++, object, static

I have found a code construct, I have never seen before and I don't know how it is called. Can someone explain it to me? I was not able to find it via google nor in this forum.

module.cpp

```
namespace NSModule
{
    CModule CModule::Instance;    //Global in this namespace
}
```

module.hpp

```
namespace NSModule
{
   class CModule
   {
       public:
           /* Some methods and such stuff */

       private:
           static CModule Instance;
   }
}
```

Why is there the class before the variable together with :: ?

```
CModule CModule::Instance;
```

I will change the title and specify my question, when I know how this is called.

Comment: Read about `static` variables, and how they are used.

Comment: Google "initialisation of static members c++"

Comment: It's called a qualified name. Pls do yourself a favor and get a book on C++.

Comment: @RustyX - Valid comment, but it should include [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to static variable c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284629/undefined-reference-to-static-variable-c)

Comment: @user0042 How is that a dupe?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Doesn't the answer explain well what's asked here?

Comment: @user0042 it tells _how_ to create one, it doesn't actually explain the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have discovered is the instantiation of a static class variable.

Until now a static variable from inside a class had to be instantiated OUTSIDE the class in which it was declared.
The instantiation is done in the same way as declaring a normal variable.

So first there is the type of the variable`CModule`, then the variable name`CModule::Instance;`.

Because this variable is from inside a class, to identify it correctly it has to be prefixed by the class name. The origin class name and variable name are separated by `::`.

Since C++17:

> A static data member may be declared `inline`. An `inline static` data member can be defined in the class definition and may specify a default member initializer. It does not need an out-of-class definition...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is known as a [static](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) class member:

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the program.
>   The static keyword is only used with the declaration of a static member, inside the class definition, but not with the definition of that static member:

```
class X { static int n; }; // declaration (uses 'static')
int X::n = 1;              // definition (does not use 'static')
```

As you can see in their example, when the variable is marked static, it is defined *outside* the class (unless for integral types such as `int`). Thus, in your code, the `static CModule Instance;` is being defined outside the class, where the definition calls the default constructor of the class `CModule` as follows:

```
  CModule  CModule::  Instance;
//type     class name variable name
```